# Validate failed: invalid checksum for migration (Evolve )

Tags: data-migration, evolve

I use evolve to automate my database changes and help keep those changes in sync across all my environments and development teams. Before I run the evolve is ok. But I am currently encountering errors in evolve, and the error information shows `Validate failed: invalid checksum for migration.` Below is the script I use.

```html
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MywamProject\evolve_2.4.0_Windows-64bit>evolve migrate mysql -c "User Id=root;password=root;Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=saas_catalogdb;" -l "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\MywamProject\\mywam.saas.backend.api\\docker-database\\evolve\\catalogdb"
Executing Migrate...
Evolve initialized.
Validate failed: invalid checksum for migration: V120__Insert_into_sa_report_proforma_detail.sql.
Validate failed: invalid checksum for migration: V120__Insert_into_sa_report_proforma_detail.sql.
```

May I know which part I am getting wrong? Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this issue by repair the checksum of already applied migrations. So instead of you put the command as `migrate`, change it to `repair`

Example:

```
evolve repair mysql -c ...the rest of the command you need
```

Should be like this:

```
evolve repair mysql -c "User Id=root;password=root;Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=saas_catalogdb;" -l "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\MywamProject\\mywam.saas.backend.api\\docker-database\\evolve\\catalogdb"
```

You can go to this link for more options on the commands and options:
https://evolve-db.netlify.app/configuration/options/